# Определение когда print() перестает писать Python

Tags: python, opencv

Всем привет! У меня появился вопрос по поводу print() в Python. Для одной фичи мне нужно реализовать функцию, где нужно будет определить когда перестанет в консоль писать значение. Можете пожалуйста подсказать. Максимум до чего я додумался это:

```
eyes2 = cv2.rectangle(img, (x+ex, y+ey), (x+ex + ew, y+ey + eh), (255, 0, 0), 2) # тут выдает значение, а я его компилирую yes
if eyes2.any():
   success2221 = "yes"
   success222 = print(success2221)
if 'yes' in success222:
   print('Есть такой текст')
if 'no' in success222:
   print('Нет такого текста')
```

Помогите мне пожалуйста!

Comment: Я ничего не понял по вашему описанию.

Comment: Смотри, мне надо чтоб программа определяла когда останавливается print что-то писать в консоль

Comment: В смысле, когда в `print` передаётся пустой аргумент?

Comment: В общем случае `print()` перестаёт писать в консоль как только завершается выполнение функции `print()`. Если параметром отключить автоматический перед строки в конце выполнения `print()`, то т.к. для консолей обычно включена построчнея буферизация, `print()` даже не начнёт ничего писать в консоль пока в тексте в явном виде не встретится перевод строки или не выставлен параметр `flush` или не сделать `flush()` в явном виде .

Comment: @Grinyov print() пишет в консоль значение до тех пор, пока она не закончит писать значение. Другими словами, никак нельзя узнать когда print() закончит писать. Если команда ( или оператор ) принт, ещё работает, то программа стоит на этой строке и выполняет эту команду ( принт ). Как только print() будет выполнен, то управление переходит к следующей команде после print(). Такое ощущение, что вы думали, что print() выполняется, а программа идёт дальше. Нет, это не так, программа ждёт, пока не закончиться полный вывод в консоль. Возможно, вам надо асинхронное программирование. А тут так нельзя

Comment: Объясняю, это цикл где print можно сказать выступает как отдельный аргумент-переменная. Может возможно как-то вычеслить когда будет выдавать пустой аргумент?

Comment: @Grinyov print() не может выступать в роли переменной или аргумента. Переменная указывает на адрес памяти, где хранится её значение, например 5. Print() это функция, или программа и она указывает на адрес памяти, где расположена команда для выполнения. Невозможно одновременно создать функцию, которая будет переменной. Вернее возможно, но тогда такая функция будет методом класса, и в классе будут свойства, которые всё равно хранятся отдельно от методов. print не может быть переменной. Программа либо выполняет действие либо запоминает информацию, но не одновременно, а по очереди, в разных местах

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я наконец то понял вопрос. Проблема в том, что `print()` возвращает `None`

`print()` всегда возвращает `None` в любом случае

```
success2221 = "yes"
success222 = print( success2221 ) # тут выводится yes
print( success222 )               # тут печатается None
```

Есть функции которые возвращают значение, например, квадратный корень, а есть функции, которые никогда ничего не возвращают в качестве результата ( они просто что-то выполняют и ничего не возвращают ). Если вы сделаете свою функцию и ничего не вернете в качестве `result`, то Python сам неявно добавит в код `result = None`. Точно так же и в функции `print()` написано, что `result = None`

Поэтому не зависимо от того, что делает `print()` её результат

`print( print( '' ) )` всегда будет `None`

Comment: в книжках по питону пишут про это